# Markowitz implied returns

Tags: portfolio

In trying to evaluate a portfolio allocation, I want to do a reverse markowitz, that is find the implied returns that would result in the current allocation to be optimal. This results in some of the implied returns to be negative, which i have a hard time grasping since all the weights are positive. Am I missing something in my calculation or could this in fact be the case?

Classical markowitz is w=E[r]*E[O] where r is a 1*n vector of returns, and O is the N*N covariance matrix. Im simply isolating for E[r] instead by E[r]=w*E[O]^-1.

Comment: This might be a better question for the Quantitative Finance exchange.

Answer (score 2):

The optimal portfolio will be optimised for high return and low variance and/or covariance.  So, in order to select negatively correlated assets to lower the covariance, sometimes an asset with some negative returns may be included.

To make a simplified example.  If assets A & B are perfectly negatively correlated their combined volatility will be zero.  That's the same volatility as cash.  Even though asset B has a negative average return, since the combined holding returns more than cash, in theory you could invest in both A and B, and even leverage the investment by borrowing cash, and the investment would be low/zero risk (based on the historical performance).

(Perfect negative correlation doesn't typically happen.)

[image]